# How to find the port number of any PC?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, tcp, port

Currently, I'm working on TCP client/server implementation in C. In that, I found that I can give any random number as a port number for my PC. Is it correct procedure? Or is there any standard port number for my PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the standard, but I say it's not. At least, I don't like to do it like that.

You can check occupied ports by parsing the outputs of programs like `netstat` and avoid using those. You can also use the method that attempts connecting on one port, and upon failure, tries another port. Unless you're really really unlucky, you should get a valid port on second try.

You should use ports within the ranges of 49152–65535. Ports below 49152 are reserved/registered.

Comment: Ozbekov: Can you support your last claim (regarding port ranges)?

Comment: @Philip: Either of `cat /etc/services`, http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml, or RFC6335.

Comment: @DevSolar: Good answer! However, I think the OP is asking what port number to use for his *server* since the OS is already taking care of assigning client ports. In that case, I wouldn't recommend using 49152-65535, since RFC6335 states that "Ports in the Dynamic Ports range (49152-65535) have been specifically set aside for local and dynamic use", both of which prohibit using them for servers.

Comment: (I'm not trying to argue here, it's just that I don't know what ports exactly to use for servers myself)

Comment: @Philip: Good point. It'd be best to find an unused port in the Reserved range then (as all "proprietary protocol" servers I've come in contact with did).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can use any port (given sufficient access rights). But server and client have to *agree* on the port, and it should not be already used by another application.

Hence, many ports are already reserved for special applications. 80 is for HTTP, 22 is for SSH and so on. The file `/etc/services` gives more detailed information.

Port numbers 0-1023 are called *Well Known Ports*, numbers 1024-49151 are called *Registered Ports* (not all of them are, but you get the idea).

Answer (score 1):

If your question is whether you can give any port number to have your server listening to, 
then you are thinking wrong, TCP/IP port numbers below 1024 are special in that normal users are not allowed to run servers on them, you can use non-privileged ports(ports > 1024). just make sure that any other application is not already using that port (above 1024) using netstat

Comment: That's correct - you should NEVER EVER use ports < 1024 unless you really know what you're doing!